# How to test whether a variable exists in the declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am using the Build User Vars [Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin) which sets various variables in the pipeline. Here is what I am currently trying:

```
wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {
    def safeBuildUser = binding.hasVariable('BUILD_USER') ? BUILD_USER : "unknown"
    echo "${safeBuildUser}"
}
```

There are times when the plugin does not set the variable. For instance, when the build was launched by an SCM branch scan. When that happens, I receive:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: BUILD_USER for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

Using `binding.hasVariable` does not appear to work because all of the builds now show "unknown".

In addition to the above, I also tried the following with no luck:

```
def safeBuildUser = BUILD_USER?: "unknown" 
def safeBuildUser = binding['BUILD_USER']?: "unknown"
def safeBuildUser = binding.variables['BUILD_USER']?: "unknown"
```

Comment: Welcome to DevOps! Just a side note: in general it's recommended to edit your post and add the extra info/details in there rather than in comments.

Comment: What is binding ? Shouldn't it be env ?

Answer (score 4):

use try/catch

```
def safeBuildUser = "unknown"
wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {
  try {
     safeBuildUser = BUILD_USER
  } catch (e) {
     echo "User not in scope, probably triggered from another job"
  }
}
echo "Builduser is: ${safeBuildUser}"
```